# Why scroll doesn't work correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, scroll

Link to jsfiddle -   https://jsfiddle.net/dn5t2mwm/3/

```
$('a.item_link').click(function(){
    var hash = this.hash, top = $(hash).offset().top;
    console.log(hash, top);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

I want to make smooth scroll. But when i account coordinates of link with anchor it returns different results. It looks like it accounts coordinates from the start of viewport - not a start of document. It works on codepen, but doesn't work on local and jsfiddle. css is disabled. Maybe you know what is wrong with it?

Comment: `var hash = this.hash`? Probably you mean `var hash = this.href`

Comment: I don't get what is wrong?! Where is the problem?

Comment: $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: top
    }, 5000); increase the scroll time . It will be more smoth

Comment: When you are click on botom links(Services CLICK THIS LINK FRO SCROLL). There are 2 links in the bottom. And these links work incorrect. So you can't use links not in the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of code:

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is because the left over height of the page is less than the scrolling area. That's the maximum it can scroll. :)

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: Yes. It was bug of jQuery as someone tell me. Solution is to make #links on blocks with height that isn't equally 0.
Thanks for helping